# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'add_arg_scope'

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to use bleeding edge version of TFLearn (https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn), a deep learning library. However on importing tflearn into python file, I encounter an attribute error, the stack trace of which is given. In case, anyone has successfully installed the same version, kindly suggest a solution to the case.

```
  import tflearn
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/models/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .dnn import DNN
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..helpers.trainer import Trainer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/helpers/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .evaluator import Evaluator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/helpers/evaluator.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ..utils import to_list
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/utils.py", line 16, in <module>
    import tflearn.variables as vs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/variables.py", line 8, in <module>
    @tf.contrib.framework.add_arg_scope
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'add_arg_scope'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of TensorFlow are you using? It might be too old. Try update your TensorFlow version to 0.8 or 0.9, that should fix that issue.

Comment: It was 0.8. I upgraded it to 0.9 and now it is working fine.